# sort a grid view based on forecolor of row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view.

I am changing the color of certain rows to red in the gridview based on logic in the row command event.

Now I would like to sort the grid view such that , the colored rows appear on the top of the grid view .
Is there any way I can do that. ? I have my code below :

aspx :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"OnRowCommand="gvMain_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                 <HeaderStyle Width="15%"></HeaderStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Std" SortExpression="Std" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblStd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Std") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList Width="200" runat="server"  id="cboStd" Font-Size="7pt" Height="12pt">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>                                         
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept" SortExpression="Dept" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDept" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Dept") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList Width="100" runat="server"  id="cboDept" Font-Size="7pt" Height="12pt">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>                                       
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                               </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void gvMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                List<StdMap> lstStd = null;

                if (gvMain.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
                {
                    lstStd = Service.GetDetails();

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    lstStd = Service.GetDetails();                    
                    ReportMap row = ((ReportMap)e.Row.DataItem);

                    if ("condition to change color to red ")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    row = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

What should i do to have all the rows with forecolor red to appear on top of the grid view ?

Comment: So what does the actual `if ("condition to change color to red ")` look like...?

Comment: How is your data source look like? Will you be able to add a flag to each of these rows in that?

Comment: I would sort it using SQL and then present it sorted in your grid.

Comment: I dont understand why I am getting down voted. My data source is a strongly typed list .

Comment: if condition is complex , I simplified my grid view in the question so that its easy to understand. In real case scenario , I also have a column Percentage and if the total percentage of a particular type are greater than 1000. I highlight all those columns in red

Comment: please tell me the reason too  when you down vote the question ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could order your grid before databinding...

something sort of like:

```
var Datasource = GetDataSource();

var OrderedDataSource = DataSource.OrderBy(Data => ConditionToChangeColorToRed(Data) ? 0 : 1);

gvMain.DataSource = OrderedDataSource;
gvMain.DataBind();
```